# How to disable :hover when scrolling on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance, mobile

I'm doing a mobile (responsive to be exact) version of an already existing desktop site that already has a lot of hefty `hover` effects on it. It often happens, than when I scroll it on mobile by touching the screen it fires some performance heavy `hover` actions like fading in a big `box-shadow` and/or animating `border`. I don't need that on mobile browser for obvious reasons and I've heard that just disabling hovers on scroll for mobile devices can result in a big performance gains.

Is there a way to easily, **temporarily** disable **all hover effects** for the time of scrolling on **mobile devices only**? Is it safe (from UX perspective) and is it worth implementing (from performance perspective)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `pointer-events: none;`

CSS:

```
.disable-hover {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var body = document.body,
    timer;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  if(!body.classList.contains('disable-hover')) {
    body.classList.add('disable-hover')
  }

  timer = setTimeout(function(){
    body.classList.remove('disable-hover')
  },500);
}, false);
```

Reference article: http://www.thecssninja.com/css/pointer-events-60fps

Comment: This is not working. If you scroll down and after scrolling try to click/touch a link fast enough, the link will not be followed because pointer-events:none is still active. Tested on iphone 6+. This is a stupid hack.  Don't use it!

Comment: Very bad idea to be using `pointer-events: none;` here. That does a lot more than just disable hover states.

Answer (score 1):

You could set for all of the hover effects to only occur when the body has a certain class.
Which would allow you to simply add / remove that class when you want to toggle the effects.

*HTML*

```
<body class="alloweffects">
<a>Some text</a>
</body>
```

*CSS*

```
.alloweffects a:hover {
color:red;
}
```

Then,to only prevent effects during scrolling you can simply listen to the *scroll* event and set the class accordingly.

Regarding performance:

I believe that the performance gain will be minimal but it'll probably vary on different browsers & devices.

But basically it should mean less event listeners, meaning more memory to deal with other things, scrolling is among them.

if we're talking about large amounts of elements I believe that the performance gain will be more significant - especially on weak devices.

Answer (score 0):

This deserves a little bit of testing but the issues are:

1. What breakpoint do you want to use for mobile (480px is usually the standard)
2. How to select all currently hoverable items
3. What effects do you need to override

Anyway a good starting point can be:

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  :hover > *  {
    // override current effects to none
  }
```

Comment: I might've misunderstood the OP, but didn't he say that he wants to prevent effects only during scroll?

Comment: I reread the question and  you may be right.. and I agree with your answer to use js to listen to the scroll events

Answer (score -2):

In your responsive css, add a x:hover class for the elements, but leave it blank.
If that does not work, negate the effect.